# Annotating ttest results in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I am trying to create a `ggplot` that will show the result of a ttest on the plot. I am now using the line `annotate("text",x=1,y=10,label='atop(bold("P-value = 0.286"))',cex=7,parse=TRUE)`. The only problem is that I have to change the value manually each time the test results change. I would like to insert `ttest$p.value` instead of the number in the label but keep it in bold.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check out [`ggpubr`](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/), it should be able to do this for you and has lots of examples

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a paste statement to help put your dynamic p-value into the annotate step. The example here is super ugly, but you will get the idea, just replace my p_val in the annotate step with your ttest$p.value:

```
rawdata <- data.frame('var1' = runif(100,1,100),
                      'var2' = runif(100,1,100))

library(ggplot2)

p_val <- .286

ggplot(rawdata,aes(x=1:100,y=var1)) + geom_line() + 
  annotate("text",x=50,y=10,label=paste0('atop(bold("p_value is ',p_val,'"))'),cex=7,parse=TRUE)
```